# Eliminate the duplicate rows from the table in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to eliminate the duplicate rows based on email from the table and retrieve all the rows without duplicates.

I have tried using distinct but I'm not getting desired results.

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT Email 
FROM 
  Users
```

**Example Table**:

| Id | Email | Username |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | sam@gmail.com | sam1122 |
| 2 | john@gmail.com | john1122 |
|  |  |  |
| 3 | sam@gmail.com | sam2233 |
| 4 | lily@gmail.com | lily@as |

**What I want to retrieve**:

| Id | Email | Username |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | john@gmail.com | john1122 |
| 2 | lily@gmail.com | lily@as |

Comment: Your output table has a record which does not appear in the input.  Please clarify/explain your sample data.

Comment: I'd do WHERE NOT EXISTS correlated subquery here, or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try using exists logic here:

```sql
SELECT Id, Email, Username
FROM Users u1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Users u2
    WHERE u2.Email = u1.Email AND
          u2.Id <> u1.Id
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Id, Email, Username
FROM Users
WHERE Email IN (
    SELECT Email
    FROM Users
    GROUP BY Email
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `left join` :

```
select u.*
from Users u
left join (
  select email, max(id) as Id
  from Users
  group by email
  having count(1) > 1
) as s on s.email = u.email
where s.email is null;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/2-6UnaWw)

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option, if you are using MySQL 8 -

```
SELECT Id, Email, Username
FROM (
    SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Email) AS cnt
    FROM Users
) t
WHERE t.cnt = 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

Below solution will work if you have `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` disabled.

```
SELECT id,
   Email,
   Username,
   count(*) AS duplicate_email_count
FROM Users
GROUP BY Email
HAVING duplicate_email_count=1
```

Comment: Getting SQL [Error](https://prnt.sc/5NnEZ9ulqoZG)

Comment: This query is non-deterministic and will only work if you have ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY disabled, which you shouldn't.